# ERPNext School module installation problem

Tags: python, erp, erpnext

I am trying to install lms app. LMS app has dependency on school app so i have to install both.
I have followed this links.

https://github.com/frappe/schools

https://github.com/frappe/lms

But I am getting the error while installing school app as described below:

```
> Ignoring dependencies of schools. To install dependencies use --resolve-deps
> Installing schools
> $ /home/frappe/frappe-bench/env/bin/python -m pip install --quiet --upgrade -e /home/frappe/frappe-bench/apps/schools
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> 
> python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
> exit code: 1
> [6 lines of output]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File “”, line 2, in
> File “”, line 34, in
> File “/home/frappe/frappe-bench/apps/schools/setup.py”, line 3, in
> from pip.req import parse_requirements
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ‘pip.req’
> [end of output]
> 
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> error: metadata-generation-failed
> 
> Encountered error while generating package metadata.
> See above for output.
> 
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for details.
> ERROR:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File “/usr/local/bin/bench”, line 8, in
> sys.exit(cli())
> File “/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bench/cli.py”, line 127, in cli
> bench_command()
> File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py”, line 1128, in call
> return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
> File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py”, line 1053, in main
> rv = self.invoke(ctx)
> File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py”, line 1659, in invoke
> return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
> File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py”, line 1395, in invoke
> return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
> File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click/core.py”, line 754, in invoke
> return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
> File “/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bench/commands/make.py”, line 159, in get_app
> get_app(
> File “/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bench/app.py”, line 444, in get_app
> app.install(verbose=verbose, skip_assets=skip_assets, restart_bench=restart_bench)
> File “/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bench/utils/render.py”, line 126, in wrapper_fn
> return fn(*args, **kwargs)
> File “/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bench/app.py”, line 242, in install
> install_app(
> File “/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bench/app.py”, line 573, in install_app
> bench.run(
> File “/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bench/bench.py”, line 48, in run
> return exec_cmd(cmd, cwd=cwd or self.cwd)
> File “/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/bench/utils/init.py”, line 155, in exec_cmd
> raise CommandFailedError
> bench.exceptions.CommandFailedError
```

Please help me with the installation.

I've tried

*$ bench get-app schools https://github.com/frappe/schools*

*$ bench install-app schools*